# Errors running Notepad++ from WSL Unbuntu

Tags: ubuntu, notepad++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm trying to run Notepad++ from WSL Ubuntu as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231568/is-there-a-way-to-open-files-with-notepad-in-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows).

Even without the alias, when I try to run notepad++, I get an Invalid argument error like this:

```
peter@Peter-PC3:~$ /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe  
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe: Invalid argument
```

Even without any argument, I get the same error

Any idea why it's not running?

## Update

After reading some of the responses, I'm seeing something similar.  It can find notepad++.exe because it's on the path at /mnt/c/Windows/system32 as well as /mnt/c/Windows.

Like @harrymc, it works, if I cd to the directory first, but if I do it from another directory, it doesn't work. From another directory, it doesn't see it as `notepad++`. If I use `notepad++.exe`, I get the same error.

```
peter@Peter-PC3:~$ /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad.exe                                         
-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad.exe: No such file or directory                                                          
peter@Peter-PC3:~$ /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe                                       
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe: Invalid argument
```

Creating a Symlink in `/usr/bin` also doesn't seem to make a difference

```
peter@Peter-PC3:/usr/bin$ pwd  
/usr/bin  
peter@Peter-PC3:/usr/bin$ ls -al note*  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 peter peter 50 Feb 14 15:06 notepad++.exe -> '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'  
peter@Peter-PC3:/usr/bin$ notepad++ /etc/passwd  
notepad++: command not found
```

## Update 2

I just installed the 64-bit version of Notepad++, in the unlikely event that had anything to do with the program.  It didn't, but it's now located in `Program Files`

Here's the requested output:

```
peter@Peter-PC3:/mnt/c/Program Files/Notepad++$ pwd
/mnt/c/Program Files/Notepad++
peter@Peter-PC3:/mnt/c/Program Files/Notepad++$ ls -la notepad*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 6443032 Jan 26 21:27 notepad++.exe
```

If I'm in the directory and I explicitly type `notepad++.exe`, then it works.  But note that if I type `note` and then try to autocomplete, it only finds `notepad.exe` and not `notepad++.exe`.

From any other directory, if I type `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe` then I get an error: `/mnt/c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe: Invalid argument`

Comment: Could you please `cd` into the installation directory of Notepad++ and see if the file exists?

Comment: Just curious - Does `notepad++.exe` from inside the directory really work, or is it `./notepad++.exe`?  The former *shouldn't* work.

Answer (score 2):

The only formulation that worked for me was:

```
cd "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/"
notepad.exe
```

This logical follow-up does **not** work:

```
"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad.exe"
```

**Edit**

Mystery solved : The Notepad that is called is simply this one:
`C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`.
This is because `C:\Windows\System32\` is in the PATH.

Another fact : Notepad++ lives in
`C:\Program Files\Notepad++`, so not where you're looking.

However, in spite of the fact that the command `ls`
can list `notepad++.exe` in this folder, it absolutely refuses
to execute it, either if directly named, or even when using any
of the formulations `'notepad++.exe'`, `notepad*.exe` or
`notepad\+\+.exe`.

This seems like some obscure bug in WSL bash.
You could signal this issue on Github
[microsoft / WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL).
Perhaps the developers will have an explanation.

Comment: Hmm, I'm seeing something similar. Even though the name of the file is actually notepad++.exe, somehow the plus signs are being ignored and it is seen as notepad.exe.  Like you, it works, if I cd to the directory first, but if I do it from another directory, it doesn't work.  From another directory, it doesn't see it as notepad++.  If I use notepad++.exe, I get the same error

Comment: @PeterKronenberg It must be a bug. You're not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Weird that some people are seeing it and some aren't.  I've got all the latest Windows updates.

Comment: I also tried things such as notepad\+\+.exe.  My `notepad++.exe` is in `Program Files (x86)`.  it's the 32-bit version.  I never upgraded to the 64-bit version since the plugin manager was not fully migrated.  That might have changed.  But good catch about notepad.exe.  I'll play around some more and see if that gives me any additional insight

Answer (score 1):

A SIMPLE way to solve this is by creating a soft link pointed at the thing you want and put it in the path.

I myself just did this (and it works PEACHY!).

1. `sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe /usr/bin/notepad++.exe`
2. `notepad++.exe /etc/passwd` from ANYWHERE. BOOM!  Mic drop.
   [image]

Problem solved.  Soft (and hard) links are your friend.  Especially in Linux.

Comment: This looks promising, but for some reason, the exe isn't working for me at all, so the sym link doesn't seem to matter

Comment: I see your update.  This makes no sense to me.  I and everyone else can run this just fine.  Hrrrmmm..  Are you able to create a softlink in your path (or $HOME and run it from there) ?

Comment: I'm getting the same results has @harrymc, so it's not just me.  I'm not sure that creating links is going to make a difference if I can't get the basic command to work from another directory.  I did do what you suggested, but I get the same results (just updated again to show this)

Comment: @PeterKronenberg   I see harrymc (from his first post) running "notepad.exe" and not notepad++.exe.  I have no issues running the notepad++.exe binary.  His text *implies* that the `+` chars must be escaped but I see no such thing.

Comment: When you try to run the binary from ./ and you are in the directory, please show us a `pwd` and a `ls -la notepad*` .. something like this: `linuxuser@v-rackerman-hp:/mnt/c/Program Files/Notepad++$ ls -la notepad++.exe
-r-xr-xr-x 1 linuxuser linuxuser 6439960 Dec 24 10:50 notepad++.exe`

Comment: @harrymc (in his example) is looking for notepad.exe in the notepad++ folder.  He will not find it there.

Comment: See latest update